# How do I set up a nodejs app and htaccess when using express?

Tags: node.js, express, .htaccess, metadata, cpanel

I'm using Cpanel to create an a NodeJS App

it is asking me the application root.
the application url
and the stratup file

The app uses express
I want to serve my usual file on port 80

I want my app to run on port 60000

The application root is myapp
application URL example.com/myapp

Cpanel create a folder /myapp in the root directory /home/user/myapp
It also create a folder /myapp in home/user/public_html/myapp

Cpanel also create an myapp.js file in /home/user/myapp

So I add my packcjage.json there a well and install dependencies.

My code uses express and listen on port 60000.

If I use the url example.com/myapp it work only with defaul generated file.
As soon as I add my real app that uses expres the browser display Cannot GET /myapp/

I read a lot of thing about htacces files but I dont understand them

the htacess file in home/user/myapp/ directory looks like this;

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/madeindr/nft"
PassengerBaseURI "/nft"
PassengerNodejs "/home/madeindr/nodevenv/nft/10/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile nft.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
```

The htaccess in /home/user/public_html is this;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And myapp.js that is working locally but not remotly is this;

```
 const express = require('express')
 var app = express();

 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Get ready for OpenSea!');
 })

 app.get('/api/token/:token_id', function(req, res) {
   const tokenId = parseInt(req.params.token_id).toString()
   

   const data = {
    "id": 0,
    "description": "My NFT",
    "external_url": "https://madeindreams.ca",
    "image": "https://madeindreams.ca/coin.png",
    "name": "My NFT 0"
  }

   res.send(data)
 })

const http_port = 60000

app.listen(http_port);
```

What do I need in these htaccess file in order to be able to reach my app?
It should be reached at example.com/myapp or with other parameters as well like
myexample.com/myapp/api/token/0.

All this is working locally but not remotly.

Th

Comment: hi @MadelInDreams, did you find any solution for this problem? i also faced it, but couldn't any solution.

Comment: I did. The problem wasn't from my htaccess file but my JS. The express session wasn't working. Not sure how i fixed it i think i switched to http instead of Express